# PrimeFaces selectOneMenu does not render when using 2 components

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I have a case below:

```
            <h:panelGrid id="panel" columns="2" >
                <h:outputLabel value="#{msgs.system_companymodule_company}" />
                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{companyModuleBean.entity.company}" >
                    <f:selectItems value="#{companyBean.companyMap}"  />
                </h:selectOneMenu>

                <h:outputLabel value="#{msgs.system_companymodule_module}" />
                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{companyModuleBean.entity.module}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{moduleBean.moduleMap}" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
            </h:panelGrid>
```

It work fine, both selectOneMenu have data! But when I change h:selectOneMenu to p:selectOneMenu, the problem appears. The first selectOneMenu does not have any data, and the second selectOneMenu has data normally.

What happen with PrimeFace selectOneMenu component?

*Note: I use PrimeFace 5 and Mojarra 2.2.7 run on Glassfish 4.0.1 b8

Comment: You should show the companyBean and moduleBean code.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? I'm having a hard time visualizing what you're describing

Comment: When using h:selectOneMenu
http://s28.postimg.org/p7ao2ko4t/jsf.jpg
</br>
When using p:selectOneMenu
http://s28.postimg.org/plc02688d/primeface.jpg